# Relationship between Sales Organization, Sales Office and Sales Group in SAP ERP

Tags: sap-erp

I want to know the relationship between Sales Organization (`VAKPA-VKORG`), Sales Office (`VAKPA-VKBUR`) and Sales Group (`VAKPA-VKGRP`) in SAP ERP.

Relationship in the sense, does One-to-One or One-to-Many relation exist between them, or do they form an hierarchy?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A **Sales Org** is assigned to a company code.

A **Division** and **Distribution Channel** are then assigned to the Sales Org (note: these can be assigned to as many sales orgs as you like in as many combinations as you like).

Together, the Sales Org, Division, and Distribution Channel form a **Sales Area**

**Sales Offices** are then assigned to the Sales Areas. You can assign a Sales Office to as many Sales Areas as you like. Likewise, multiple **Sales Groups** can be assigned to a single Sales Office... but also you can assign one Sales Group to multiple Sales Offices.

In summary:

- 1 Company Code : Many Sales Orgs
- {Sales Org, Division, Dist. Ch.} -> 1 Sales Area (you can have as many sales areas as there are permutations of the three)
- Many Sales Offices : Many Sales Areas
- Many Sales Groups : Many Sales Offices

Answer (score 1):

From SAP Help:

> #### Sales Group
>
> The definition of sales groups is optional. You can use the SD system without creating sales groups.
>
> - You can assign a sales group to one or more sales offices.

> #### Sales Office
>
> The definition of sales offices is optional. You can use the SD System without creating sales offices.
>
> - You assign a sales office to one or more sales areas.

> #### Sales Organization
>
> - Legally, a sales organization is included in exactly one company code.
> - You assign sales offices and your own employees to a sales organization.
> - All items in a sales & distribution document, that is, all items of an order, delivery or a billing document belong to a sales organization.

---

#### Summary

It looks like you have an hierarchical structure starting at the Sales Org with a `0:n`-relationship to Sales Office which in turn have a `0:n`-relationship to Sales Group.

- Sales Group check table is `TVKGR`.
- Sales Office check table is `TVBUR`.
- Sales Org check table is `TVKO`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the sales offices assigned to sales groups by checking the table TVBVK in Tcode SE16N